# How to have a second level of labels on x-axis

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is so basic, I'm kind of embarrassed, but I'm trying to add fractions on a number line and it looks like crap. Is there a way to drop fractions to a different level or something.  I tried `[below left]`but that didn't look right either. Looking for something like `[below below]` to double up the drop, but I couldn't find an answer anywhere.

```
\documentclass[letter]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[latex-latex] (-1.5,0) -- (5.5,0);% the x-axis
\foreach \x in  {-1,...,5} % tick marks
\draw (\x,0) -- (\x,-3pt);
\foreach \x in {-1,...,5} % the numbers
\node [below] at (\x,-0.1) {$\x$};
\node [above] at (1.67,0.5) {A};
\node [below] at (1.67,-0) {1$\frac{2}{3}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Yes, of course, there are advanced positioning methods available, e.g. when you load `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}`. And you could do `\node [below=5pt] at (1.67,-0) {1$\frac{2}{3}$};`, but IMHO `\node [below=5pt] at (1.67,-0) {$\frac{5}{3}$};` looks better. If you load the `fp` package and the `fpu` tikz library, you could also do something like `\pgfmathprintnumber[frac]{0.5}`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfectly.  I'm going to go read up on these packages.

Comment: I fixed some problems in the code and markup of your post. I think you had the code selected when you added the image. As a result, the code was used as the alt text for the image (as far as the markup was concerned), and when you do that all `[` and `]` in the code are changed to `\[` and `\]`, respectively. I.e. the brackets in the code are escaped, so they don't interfere with the brackets in the markdown code for image inclusion (that looks like `[![alt text][1]][1]`, selected text will be used as `alt text`).

Comment: @marmot Do you want to post this as an answer so that the question can be closed?

Answer (score 2):

Towards an answer ... don't know precisely what you want... `positioning` allows, as its name suggest, for an intuitive positioning. It also helps to work with the `anchor=base` key in this case, I'd say.

```
\documentclass[letter]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[latex-latex] (-1.5,0) -- (5.5,0);% the x-axis
\foreach \x in  {-1,...,5} % tick marks
\draw (\x,0) -- (\x,-3pt);
\foreach \x in {-1,...,5} % the numbers
{\node [below=12pt,anchor=base] at (\x,0) {$\x$};}
\node [above=12pt,anchor=base] at (5/3,0) {A};
\node [below=12pt,anchor=base] at (5/3,-0) {$\frac{5}{3}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]